# PYTHON вставка текста в форму PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Я понимаю, что уже миллион постов на эту тему, но почему-то **ни один** из этих способов **не работает с моим файлом**.

Код:

```
import fillpdf
from fillpdf import fillpdfs

input_pdf_path = "R11001.pdf"
fillpdfs.get_form_fields(input_pdf_path)
fillpdfs.print_form_fields(input_pdf_path, sort=False, page_number=None)

data_dict = {
'0': 'Name SecondName',
}

fillpdfs.write_fillable_pdf(input_pdf_path, 'new.pdf', data_dict)
fillpdfs.flatten_pdf('new.pdf', 'new.pdf')
```

Ссылка на сам файл [PDF](https://www.nalog.gov.ru/cdn/form/4162139.pdf).

Я так же пробовал **aspose.pdf** и он прекрасно справился, но использовать это ПО бесплатно является невозможным.
Прошу опытного взгляда на эту проблему.

Comment: На русском языке почти не через какой модуль не вставляется.